# How to get section of UITableView from inside a child UICollectionview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift3, indexpath

I have a `UITableView` with a `UICollectionView` within each of its rows like the illustration below.

[image: collectionviews within tableviews]

*source: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/*

The intention of my app is to display a character set of a language within each table view row. Each character is contained within a collection view cell of the collectionview within the corresponding row.

[image: my app]

**The problem I am having is that the english character set is being displayed for every tableview row.**

This is because each collectionview only has one section and thus every collectionview uses the same `indexPath.section` value of zero.

What I need to do is get the section value of the table view cells that the collectionviews are within and somehow pass that to

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

I've tried several things but I can't find a way to access the tableview section value from the collectionview within it.

My code is a bit of a mess but the generally important parts are

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HorizontalSlideCell", for: indexPath)

    return cell
}

...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InnerCollectionViewCell",
                                                  for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    //format inner collectionview cells

    //indexPath.section is the collectionview section index but needs to be its parent tableview section's index. How do I get it? 
    cellCharLabel?.text = Languages.sharedInstance.alphabets[indexPath.section].set[indexPath.row].char
    cellCharLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    cellCharLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40)

    cell.contentView.addSubview(cellCharLabel!)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `collectionView` tag to make it.
`CollectionView` should be the subview of `tableViewCell`. That is the `collectionView` can be the property of your customize `TableViewCell`  Seems you are using `Prototype Cell`.

```
class YourCustomizeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   let collectionView: CollectionView
   ...
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HorizontalSlideCell", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomizeTableViewCell
   cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row

   return cell
}

...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InnerCollectionViewCell",
                                              for: indexPath as IndexPath)


//indexPath.section is the collectionview section index but needs to be its parent tableview section's index. How do I get it? 
cellCharLabel?.text = Languages.sharedInstance.alphabets[collectionView.tag].set[indexPath.row].char
 ...
return cell
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Just what I was looking for!

Comment: if we are passing tag in collection view, but due to reusable table view cell i am getting previous cell and previous tag.

Comment: @user1960279 You see after ```cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row``` the collectionView's tag was reassigned. Where did you use the tag?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a custom UITableViewCell class with an instance of a UICollectionView, so you just need to pass it the section index when you call cellForRowAtIndexPath.

You would need to make a var in the tableViewCell class to hold the section index.

```
 class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
      var sectionIndex:Int?

 }
```

Then when calling cellForRow... you just pass in the section to that cell.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HorizontalSlideCell", for: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell
    cell.sectionIndex = indexPath.section
    return cell
}
```

Not sure how you are loading data into the collection views as you aren't showing that but once your table view cell has the section you can then do a number of things to load your data.

Let me know if you need more detail

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: sorry I still haven't get how to access sectionIndex from CollectionViewCell , could you provide an example? thanks (VERY URGENT)